# Export Rasters from geodatabase containing specific words in title

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a file geodatabase containing +200 rasters. I want to export a selection of these based on words in the middle of the file name. Example file names below:

Bat_day_male

Bat_night_male

Frog_day_male

Frog_night_male

Cat_day_male

Cat_night_male

How do I select only the files containing "day" to export to another filegeodatabase? I would like to do this in model builder using an iterator if possible.

Comment: Would be easy using arcpy. I can post an arcpy answer if you are ok with this

Comment: yes please, I can give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arcpy. List the rasters using ListRasters and copy to new fgdb. Change input and output databases and execute in python window:

```
import arcpy, os

input_fgdb = r'C:\Somedatabase.gdb'
output_fgdb = r'C:\Someoutputdatabase.gdb'

arcpy.env.workspace = input_fgdb
rasterlist = [r for r in arcpy.ListRasters() if 'day' in r]

for r in rasterlist:
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(in_raster=r, out_rasterdataset=os.path.join(output_fgdb,r))
```

(This will copy all rasters with "day" in the name, regardless of the position of "day" in the raster name)